# Can I send a 'waitfor' signal to Windows?

Tags: windows, scripts

The [`waitfor`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731613%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command in Windows can be used to either wait for or send arbitrary signals over the network. It's useful for synchronizing scripts across multiple machines.

Can I generate one of these signals in Ubuntu for a waiting Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best I can suggest is that you try running the waitfor.exe via wine. There just doesn't seem to be any information around about the protocols for this signalling.